# File reading and processing problem in Python

Tags: python

Although my code reads the books.txt file in the project correctly, I cannot perform integer comparison properly.

After reading the data in books.txt, I wanted to filter the books according to their publication year, but I could not obtain accurate data as a result of the comparisons I made.

## Function:

```
def filter_by_release_year(self):
    try:
        year = int(input("Enter release year: "))
        current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
        if year > current_year:
            print("Invalid year. Please enter a valid release year.")
            return
        self.file.seek(0)
        books = self.file.readlines()
        filtered_books = []
        second_year = 0
        choiceTwo = "0"
        print("\nFilter Options:")
        print(f'1. Books published in "{year}"')
        print(f'2. Books published in "{year}" and AFTER')
        print(f'3. Books published in "{year}" and BEFORE')
        print(f'4. Books published between "{year}" and "second year"')
        choiceTwo = input("Enter your filter option(1-4): ")
        if choiceTwo == "4":
            second_year = int(input("Enter second release year: "))
            if second_year > current_year:
                print("Invalid second year. Please enter a valid release year.")
        if second_year < year:
            temp = year
            year = second_year
            second_year = temp

        for book in books:
            book_info = book.strip().split(",")
            print(book_info)
            book_year: int = int(book_info[2])
            if choiceTwo == "1" and book_year == year: # Option 1
                filtered_books.append(f"{book.strip()}")
            elif choiceTwo == "2" and year <= book_year:  # Option 2
                filtered_books.append(f"{book.strip()}")
            elif choiceTwo == "3 " and book_year <= year:  # Option 3
                filtered_books.append(f"{book.strip()}")
            elif choiceTwo == "4" and year <= book_year <= second_year: # Option 4
                filtered_books.append(f"{book.strip()}")

        if not filtered_books:
            print("No books found matching the filter criteria.")
        else:
            print("Filtered Books:")
            for index, book in enumerate(filtered_books, start=1):
                print(f"{index}. {book}")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid year.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Unable to filter books by release year - {e}")
```

## Output:

```
Filter Options:
1. Filter by Book Title
2. Filter by Author
3. Filter by Release Year
4. Filter by Number of Pages
5. Sort Books
Enter your filter option: 3
Enter release year: 2000

Filter Options:
1. Books published in "2000"
2. Books published in "2000" and AFTER
3. Books published in "2000" and BEFORE
4. Books published between "2000" and "second year"
Enter your filter option(1-4): 1
No books found matching the filter criteria.
```

Option 4 Works Correctly but in other options, I get wrong data or no results at all.

## Output of Option 4:

```
Filter Options:
1. Filter by Book Title
2. Filter by Author
3. Filter by Release Year
4. Filter by Number of Pages
5. Sort Books
Enter your filter option: 3
Enter release year: 2005

Filter Options:
1. Books published in "2005"
2. Books published in "2005" and AFTER
3. Books published in "2005" and BEFORE
4. Books published between "2005" and "second year"
Enter your filter option(1-4): 4
Enter second release year: 2010

Filtered Books:
1. Harry Potter ve Melez Prens,J.K. Rowling,2005,607
2. Harry Potter ve Ölüm Yadigarları,J.K. Rowling,2007,784
3. Kayıp Sembol,Dan Brown,2009,504
4. Zahir,Paulo Coelho,2005,208
5. A Thousand Splendid Suns,Khaled Hosseini,2007,368
```

When I Try Debug like this:

```
            for book in books:
                book_info = book.strip().split(",")
                print(book_info)
                book_year: int = int(book_info[2])
                if book_year == year:
                    print("equal\n")
                if book_year >= year:
                    print("equal or bigger\n")
                if book_year <= year:
                    print("equal or smaller\n")
                if choiceTwo == "1":
                    print("1 is chosed")
                if choiceTwo == "2":
                    print("2 is chosed")
                if choiceTwo == "3":
                    print("3 is chosed")
```

The Ouput:

```
Filter Options:
1. Books published in "2000"
2. Books published in "2000" and AFTER
3. Books published in "2000" and BEFORE
4. Books published between "2000" and "second year"
Enter your filter option(1-4): 1
['Harry Potter ve Azkaban Tutsağı', 'J.K. Rowling', '1999', '435']
equal or bigger

1 is chosed
['Harry Potter ve Ateş Kadehi', 'J.K. Rowling', '2000', '766']
equal or bigger

1 is chosed
['Harry Potter ve Zümrüdüanka Yoldaşlığı', 'J.K. Rowling', '2003', '1107']
equal or bigger

1 is chosed
```

According to this test, the comparisons  do not work properly, always giving output equal to or greater than 2000 integer value.

Comment: Strip down your code to the necessary stuff that does not work. To the bare minimum to reproduce your problem. E.g. create a txt file with shuffled years, and ask the user for a sort oder. This is called a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Without the overhead of your whole application which is not needed for your problem. Like this, you will find the problem on your own. Break problems into smaller pieces.

Comment: When I try small pieces of code, the problem occurs in the integer comparison part.
`if book_year == year: print("equal")`

`if choiceTwo == "1": print("1 is chosed")`

`if choiceTwo == "1" and book_year == year: print(book_year)`
 Publication year and user input are not compared correctly. But the same process works correctly for Option 4 `elif choiceTwo == "4" and year <= book_year <= second_year:`

Answer (score 1):

I asked someone knowledgeable for help and he pointed out my mistake. The reason for the error is that the if block was written in the wrong place.:

```
            if choiceTwo == "4":
                second_year = int(input("Enter second release year: "))
                if second_year > current_year:
                    print("Invalid second year. Please enter a valid release year.")
            if second_year < year:
                    temp = year
                    year = second_year
                    second_year = temp
```

Corrected version:

```
            if choiceTwo == "4":
                second_year = int(input("Enter second release year: "))
                if second_year > current_year:
                    print("Invalid second year. Please enter a valid release year.")
                if second_year < year:
                    temp = year
                    year = second_year
                    second_year = temp
```